# How do I import the D3 library into my project file structure?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to not rely on the basic code as follows in my file:

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to include the d3 library in my file structure. I have created a "libs" file in my project. Here is the link to the page to download the d3 library: https://github.com/d3/d3 My question is after downloading the necessary files from github, do I simply create a d3 folder in my libs folder and place the files there? If so, do I reference a specific file or just the folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways of importing other people's code. You could, as you suggested, just download the [latest release](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases) and copy the `d3.js` or `d3.min.js` into a `lib/` directory, then import it like so:

```
<script src="lib/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, if you're using a package manager like `npm` or `bower`, you could just install it using that, as recommended in the README. There's also a resource showing how you could use a bundler like [Rollup](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/bb09af4c39c79cffcde4) to package D3 with all of your other libraries.

Comment: if I use the node package manager and the `npm install` command, will I still have to use the `<script src='etc.js'></script>`?

Comment: Yes, you will. It should be installed somewhere in the `node_modules` folder but you'll be able to import it as normal.

Answer (score 2):

You must include your local copy of D3 like so:

```
<script src="libs/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

No need to create a separate folder if you'll use just D3. If you need other dependencies use like this:

```
    <script src="libs/d3/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="libs/d3/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/d3/d3-queue.v2.min.js"></script>
```